# Firebase security rules: allow update only one field

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to update only one field (activeStatus) and secure all other fields not editable.[image: All fields]

I already try `request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["activeStatus"])`

Comment: "not working for me" is hard to help with. Please edit your question to [show the error you get, the minimal, complete rules and the corresponding code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i do the change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['activeStatus'])
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that users can only update the `activeStatus` field, your update rule would look something like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function is_unchanged(key) {
      let in_old = key in resource.data;
      let in_new = key in request.resource.data;
      return (!in_old && !in_new)
        || (
          in_old && in_new
          && request.resource.data[key] == resource.data[key]
        );
    }

    match /some/{document} {
      allow update: if is_unchanged('available')
        && is_unchanged('checkBeforeBuy')
        && is_unchanged('description')
        // Repeat for all fields that should not change
        && is_unchanged('validity');
        
    }
  }
}
```